# How to properly use Django ORM Count with shopping cart

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have such models structure and I need to get information about how many pizzas was ordered.
I did something like this `PizzaOrder.objects.all().values('pizza').annotate(total=Count('pizza'))`. It works fine for orders where `count` in `PizzaOrder` equals to 1, but if `count` more than 1, it displays wrong count number. So I want somehow to connect Django `Count` with my field `count` in order to know how many pizzas was ordered.

**models.py**

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    pizzas = models.ManyToManyField(to='Pizza', through='PizzaOrder')


class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Pizza,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Order,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    count = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Comment: Do you want to find how many pizzas were ordered for an instance of `Order` or just the total irrespective of `Order`? Or perhaps with respect to some individual pizza?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, the total irrespective of `Order`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Count` you need to use the [`Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum) function:

```
# annotating on the orders:
orders = Order.objects.annotate(total=Sum('pizzaorder__count'))

for order in orders:
    print(order.order_number, order.total)


# annotating on the pizzas:
pizzas = Pizza.objects.annotate(total=Sum('pizzaorder__count'))

for pizza in pizzas:
    print(pizza.name, pizza.total)


# aggregating irrespective of order / pizza:
pizza_count = PizzaOrder.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('count'))['total']

print(pizza_count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not that I wanted, but with help of your answer I got the expected result `pizza_count = PizzaOrder.objects.values('pizza').annotate(total=Sum('count'))`

Comment: @truefan4ever `pizzas = Pizza.objects.annotate(total=Sum('pizzaorder__count'))` will do that too, infact it is better since then you also have the pizza names now and all other fields present on the `Pizza` model which you will lose if you use group by.